# vector of periods in R

Tags: r

I am using R to make a vector that alternates between 1000 and a period `.`

this is what I have written in R:

```
rep(1000:".",c(1,10))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in 1000:"." : NA/NaN argument In addition: Warning message: NAs
>   introduced by coercion

How do I force to accept period in this vector?

Answer (score 3):

Vectors must have everything of the same type. A period is a string/character and can't be a numeric, so your vector must be a character vector.

```
rep(c("1000", "."), 10)
# [1]  "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."    
# [11] "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."    "1000" "."
```

The colon, `:`  is used to generate a sequence of integers. For example

```
3:7
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

Though I wouldn't advise it, you can use it to create non-integer sequences of step-size one:

```
2.1:5.9
# [1] 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1
```

But since `.` isn't an integer, (nor is `"."`), you can't use it with a colon. Instead you need to create your base string for repetition using the `c()` function as above.

Comment: yes, but `c(1000,".")` will get coerced to `c("1000",".")` anyway ... the OP's real problem is the misuse/confusion over the colon operator